# Need all assigned task in activiti engine

Tags: java

If I want to get all the tasks which are assigned then which method should I use because I am new here.

I am getting any method which will return all the assigned tasks there is one method but taskAssignee() but that will for specific user.

Below is the code for reference

```
List<Task> allTaskList taskservice.createTaskQuery().taskAssignee(null).list();

logger.info("allTaskList size: {}", allTaskList.size());

List TaskFilterServiceResponseModel> customAssignedTaskList = new ArrayList<>();

TaskFilterServiceResponseModel model = new TaskFilterServiceResponseModel();

List<TaskFilterServiceDataModel> datalist = new ArrayList<>( );

model.setTotal(0);

model.setSize(0);

model.setStart(0);
```

Comment: This clearly isn't from code that you've tried to run, because it has several syntax errors in it.  You should make an attempt first and tell us what did or didn't work.  As it is, I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to accomplish.  My guess is that you want to make a method that will accept a List<Task> and return a new List<Task> which is filtered to show only those that have taskAssignee != null.  Is that it?

Comment: Could you please able to tell me how we can get?

Comment: I mean to say is there any method using which we can get?

Comment: How we can get all tasks which are assigned